# Adjusting width around figures

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure, wrap

This is a screenshot of a page of a textbook I am writing. The image is a jpg file that was inserted using the environment wrapfigure  of the package wrapfig.

How can I force the paragraph starting with "Una rappresentazione grafica ..." to be typeset at the normal page width?

[image]

Comment: Can you please prepare an extract from your book, which shows this page and its problem, so we can copy, compile and improve it? Thank you